# Under what conditions may a newly married couple go on birth control?

Tags: halacha, marriage, medicine, pregnancy-birth, family-members

Which halachic conditions may allow a couple to go on birth control upon getting married?

Is the desire to work on building a solid relationship between man and wife before starting a family a valid halachic reason to go on birth control for the first 6 months or year?

Comment: There is exactly one _halakhic_ consideration for any question like this: what your rabbi said. Different rabbis will give completely different answers to this question and it depends greatly on your personal circumstances.

Comment: @Daniel How do you know that this is different form any other halakhic question in which the existence of poskim does not negate the existence of halakha that one can independently study and observe?

Comment: Basically, because there is no clear answer. Only one that has experience with paskening (shimush) should make such decisions

Comment: Why specifically a new marriage?

Comment: @DonielF I assume the OP just put it down in case it might make a difference in psak. I heard one posek say that lots of people get different psaks because they leave out important details.

Comment: https://www.academia.edu/41113803/The_Halakhic_Parameters_of_Delaying_Procreation

Answer (score 1):

Someone told me the following principles, which he said are in gemarah niddah.

1. Health of mother is at risk. (e.g. a year after c section)
2. Psychological well being of the person. (e.g. Shalom bais not there, overwhelmed, depressed.)
3. Rabanim are meikel to use birth control for 2 years after a birth.

Comment: In Gemoro Meneket the child of her first husband Meshamashet Bemoch with the second husband. I can not search the precise place here.

Answer (score 0):

See section 3 of [this article](http://www.yoatzot.org/womens-health-and-halacha/?id=2128) for a summary of R. Yehudah Henkin's approach to this issue.  R. Baruch Simon discusses the issue [here](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/752719/%20ADMIN%20ADMIN/Thanksgiving%20Shiur%20-%20Delaying%20Mitzvos) (from 74:00 onwards) - he places it in the general context of heterim to delay performing a  mitzvas aseih.

Comment: Could you edit in some info?